# Is there an easy way to globalize a variable in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, global

Im wondering if there is a simple way to globalize a variable in a python class. Im trying this example below but getting this  following error message:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'gold' referenced before assignment

I dont want to type 'global gold' in every function.

```
gold = 10
class economy:
    global gold

   def income(self):
        gold+=5

    def expense(self):
        gold-=5
```

Comment: No there isn't. Python purposefully makes you write `global gold` to discourage you from making a horrible design decision like what you are trying to do right now. The *whole point* of classes is to avoid global, mutable state. There is definitely a better solution.

Comment: Either make it a class or an instance attribute. Don't make it global.

Comment: `global gold` would *only* apply to the code directly executed in the `class` statement when defining the class. It doesn't apply to any of the methods. Move the `global` statement into *each of the methods*.

Comment: Put differently: no, that's not possible, and it really shouldn't be.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the answers! Just wanted to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better put gold in class, and reference from instance

```
class economy:
    def __init__(self, gold):
        self.gold = gold
    def income(self):
        self.gold+=5
    def expense(self):
        self.gold-=5

a = economy(90)
a.income()
a.gold # 95
a.expense()
a.gold # 90
```

Comment: Unless you make sure that `economy` is a singleton (which it currently isn't), then there are multiple `gold` variables: one per instance of `economy`.

Comment: @HannesOvrén but that's fine. This is why people have considered singletons an antipattern: they merely put a thin veneer on mutable, global state

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not advocating the use of singletons. It seems like OP wanted `gold` to be global, and this solution makes it non-global, and is thus a bad answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

The most accessible variable in the class is an attribute and to use it outside of the class you can create a getVariable function like this :

```
gold = 10

class economy:
   gold = None 

   def __init__(self,gold) :
        self.gold = gold 

   def income(self):
        self.gold+=5

    def expense(self):
        self.gold-=5

    def getGold(self) :
        return self.gold

# to get the gold value from the object :
gold = economy(gold).getGold()
```